# Copiar valor de select a input con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

¿Cómo hacer que un `select` creado con PHP envíe su valor a un `input` creado con PHP?

De este `select`:

```
<th>Proveedor</th>
<td>
    <select name="prov_id" id="prov_id">
        <?php
        if (count($lstProvedores) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($lstProvedores as $idx => $campo)
            {
                echo "<option value='{$campo->prov_id}'>$campo->prov_pf_nombre</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

A este `input`:

```
  <?php
  if (count($lstProvedores) > 0) {
      foreach ($lstProvedores as $idx => $campo) {
              echo "<input  value='{$campo->prov_contact_correo}'/>";
      }
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
   $(document).on('change','#mySelect',function(){ //detectamos el evento change
     var value = $(this).val();//sacamos el valor del select
      $('#myInput').val(value);//le agregamos el valor al input (notese que el input debe tener un ID para que le caiga el valor)
    });
  });

</script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="UNO">Valor uno</option>
  <option value="DOS">Valor dos</option>
  <option value="TRES">Valor tres</option>
</select>

<input id="myInput">
```

El input debe tener un ID para que le puedas poner el dato que estas sacando del select.

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada PHP corre del lado del servidor, y lo que tu quieres hacer es que al seleccionar una opción de lado del cliente se llene automáticamente un input segun la seleccion.

para este caso requiere de javascript o Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.client-select').on('change',function(){
         if($(this).val() != "default"){
            $('.clientuserid').val($(this).val());
        }else{
            $('.clientuserid').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

donde `clientuserid` es el ID de tu input html

si lo que deseas es que al escoger el option, haga una consulta al servidor y la respuesta la escriba en el input, deberas usar ajax.

Comment: de que manera podría hacer eso es que tengo una idea pero no se como plantearla

Comment: Cual parte, quieres hacer ??

Comment: ya lo pude hacer lo hice con ajax

Comment: que bueno puede seleccionar la respuesta que mas te ayudo . y añade la respuesta.